# ImportError: no module named Tkinter (Running python with NotePad++'s NppExec)

Tags: python, tkinter, notepad++, importerror, nppexec

I'm trying to run a python file using Notepad++'s NppExec plugin.  My file attempts to import Tkinter using the line "from Tkinter import * ". With NppExec, I run the following script:

```
python "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

or sometimes

```
python -i "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"
```

In either case, I get the error "ImportError:  No module named Tkinter".  I find this odd, because if I run my python file using any other method (IDLE, directly from command line, or even with Npp's built in Run function), I get no errors, and Tkinter imports correctly.

I'm running Windows 7, if it makes a difference.

Thanks in advance for your help!
-Sam

Comment: print sys.path in both cases?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is simple -- the python command you are running does not have a module named Tkinter. The *cause* of the problem is more difficult to understand without more information. My first guess would be that NppExec is running a different version of python than you think it is running, and this version of python either doesn't have tkinter installed, or has it installed under a different name (python 2 is Tkinter and python 3 is tkinter).

Try using NppExec to run a script that does the following:

```
import sys
print sys.executable
print sys.path
```

The output from those commands should give you enough information to debug the problem.

Comment: I also have Lilypond installed on my computer, which in its libraries has an older version of python.  NppExec was using this version, so I just switched the command I was sending NppExec:   `C:\Python27\python.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)"`

and now everything works great!  thanks!

Comment: python 2 is Tkinter and python 3 is tkinter NAILED it!